# Should Navigation Drawer items be static or dynamic?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Navigation Drawer items should static or dynamic android? Like Item1, Item2, Item3

[image]

Comment: What kind of question is this? [Don't ask question like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: if you are able answer the question plz answer it @YosiPramajaya

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what kind of menu you want to display.

Do you want the menu to be flexible, changeable during runtime or whenever you want? Go for the dynamic (set it programmatically, add `MenuItem` that you like)

Else, you can use static (setup in menu resources)